# XAMPP 1.7.3 and MSSQL 2016 connection

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, xampp

I'm using an old version of XAMPP (1.7.3) to run a PHP old script on many MSSQL databases (2008,2012,2014).
when tried to connect MSSQL 2016 and 2017 I'm getting connection errors "Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server"

the log doesn't have any data related to this error to debug.

Comment: Show us your code, otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: $myServer = ".\sql2016";
$myUser = "sa";
$myPass = "hgfdSHFHdsRFFS3546";
$myDB = "test"; $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)    or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer. Error: " . mssql_get_last_message());